# Redirecting OpenVPN traffic to Burp Suite

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I have a Linux Mint VM that I spun up as a transparent proxy for iOS devices. My intention is to tunnel all traffic from the iOS device through the VM and intercept it with Burp Suite, as an application I'm analyzing does not respect system proxy settings (the app is written in Xamarin).

Previous guides in [making a transparent proxy](http://www.flinkd.org/proxying-non-proxy-aware-applications-with-burp-and-pptp/) required a PPTP VPN, which is no longer supported by iOS 10 and above. I tried making an OpenVPN server on the VM and the iptables rules are as follows (loosely based on the guide above):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Some context for the rules above: `enp0s3` is my VM's bridged adapter, `tun0` is the default OpenVPN interface.

The problem is that the VPN only works when the `PREROUTING` rules do not exist. If I add in the `PREROUTING` rules to iptables, the client can't connect to any webpage on the Internet (but is curiously able to connect to local web servers within the network).

Another [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/357411/redirect-openvpn-gateway-traffic-to-privoxy) I tried which did not work is:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --source 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Is there a way to forward/redirect traffic from OpenVPN (or indeed any other modern VPN such as L2TP over IPSec, Cisco IPSec) to Burp Suite for traffic analysis, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the option 'Support invisible proxying' in Burp's options.

[image: Burp options request handling]

Comment: Well I'll be damned, that actually worked. I completely forgot about enabling invisible proxying. Thank you!

For future reference for other people attempting to MITM themselves with OpenVPN and Burp Suite, simply execute the first set of `iptables` rules (taking into account your network interface for the 3rd line) and double check your invisible proxying setting.